# Find the joint distribution of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. Are $Y_1 \text{ and } Y_2$ independent?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Consider two urns, urn A and urn B. In urn A, there are 3 balls numbered 0,1,2. In urn B there are 6 balls numbered 1,2,3,4,5,6. A ball is drawn from urn A, then a ball is drawn from urn B. Define $X_A$ as the number of the ball from urn A and $X_B$ the number of the ball drawn form urn B. What is the joint distribution of $(X_A, X_B)$. Let $Y_1 = X_A X_B$ and $Y_2 = \text{max}\{X_A, X_B\}$. Find the joint distribution of $(Y_1, Y_2)$. Hint: make a table. Find the marginal distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent? Justify your answer using part (b).

I tried making the table, not sure if it's correct or not. Also I don't know how to use it to check whether $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent or not?
$$
\begin{array} {l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
 &  &     &     & X_B    &     &     &     \\ \hline
 &  & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\ \hline
&0  & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 \\ \hline
X_A&1  & 1/18 & 1/18    & 1/18    & 1/18    & 1/18    & 1/18    \\ \hline
&2  & 1/18    & 1/18  & 1/18    & 1/18    & 1/18    & 1/18    
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array} {l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
 &  &     &     & Y_2    &     &     &     \\ \hline
 &  & 1    & 2    & 3    & 4    & 5    & 6    \\ \hline
&0  & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 & 1/18 \\ \hline
&1  & 1/18 & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    \\ \hline
&2  & 0    & 1/9  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    \\ \hline
&3  & 0    & 0    & 1/18 & 0    & 0    & 0    \\ \hline
Y_1&4  & 0    & 1/18 & 0    & 1/18 & 0    & 0    \\ \hline
&5  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 1/18 & 0    \\ \hline
&6  & 0    & 0    & 1/18 & 0    & 0    & 1/18 \\ \hline
&8  & 0    & 0    & 0    & 1/18 & 0    & 0    \\ \hline
&10 & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 1/18 & 0    \\ \hline
&12 & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 0    & 1/18
\end{array}
$$